# JSON-LD GTM Tag for BlogPosting

Tags: schema.org, structured-data, json-ld, google-tag-manager

I'd like to do schema markup for my wordpress blog in Google Tag Manager. I've integrated the variables for Image url and Date Published into my JSON-LD GTM Tag, but I get an error in the Google Structured Data Testing Tool saying:

url - false (The value provided for image.url must be a valid URL.)

datePublished - false (Cannot understand the value false as a date/time. Learn more about date/time formats.)

Can you please help me to find out what do I do wrong?

Here is a part of my tag:
[image]

My variable for Image Blog
[image]

My variable for Date Published:
[image]

Error in the Google Testing Tool:
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you test in the SDTT, the JSON-LD after or before the variables are replaced with the data?

Comment: I'm testing whether Google gets my structured data correctly... I was basically following the steps from this article to set-up the markup https://moz.com/blog/using-google-tag-manager-to-dynamically-generate-schema-org-json-ld-tags

Comment: Refer to the Google: Don’t Rely on Google Tag Manager for Structured Data http://www.thesempost.com/google-dont-rely-google-tag-manager-structured-data/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your meta tags don't exist or are not properly populated in your blog post pages. Please check and confirm if they are there in the first place so that Google Tag Manager can then extract the values correctly.